# Can't assemble the .s file that was generated by llc using arm-none-eabi-as?

Tags: arm, llvm, llc

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.

I compiled a bitcode using llc.exe and get a .s file (test.s).
The command that I used to create test.s is as below.

```
llc -march=thumb -mattr=thumb2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 main.bc -o test.s
```

Yes, my target board is cortex-m3 (stm32l series) and I created makefile as below to create .bin file.

```
bin: test.s
    @echo "Running target all"
    arm-none-eabi-as c:/backend/files/test.s -o c:/backend/files/test.o
    arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x08000000 c:/backend/files/test.o -o c:/backend/files/test.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objdump -D c:/backend/files/test.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy c:/backend/files/test.elf -O binary c:/backend/files/test.bin

clean:
    @echo "Running target clean"
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.bin
```

makefile is simple. It's goal is to create test.bin from test.s file.

test.s file is as below. I created test.s file

```
    .text
    .syntax unified
    .file   "main.bc"
    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  main                    ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align    1
    .code16                         ; @main
    .thumb_func
main:
; %bb.0:
    sub sp, #8
    movs    r0, #10
    movs    r1, #20
    cmp r0, #21
    str r0, [sp, #4]
    str r1, [sp]
    blo ($MBB0_2)
; %bb.1:
    ldr r0, [sp, #4]
    adds    r0, #1
    str r0, [sp, #4]
$MBB0_2:
    add sp, #8
    bx  lr
                                        ; -- End function
```

EveryThing went smoothly until here. Here I executed make.exe to create test.bin but I got a error as below.

[image]

I don't know if the .s file that generated by llc.exe is not format of cortex-m3.

Could someone help me?
I want to know what cause of problem is.

Thanks for reading.

------------------------------- update -----------------------------------

Original code is as below. The code was write just test purpose.

```
void main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    if ( a > b) a ++;
}
```

The bitcode is as below. The bitcode was generated manually.

```
define void @main()
{
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
%2 = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 10, i32* %1, align 4
store i32 20, i32* %2, align 4
%3 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
%4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
%5 = icmp ugt i32 %3, %4
br i1 %5, label %6, label %9

;%6
%7 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
%8 = add nsw i32 %7, 1
store i32 %8, i32* %1, align 4
br label %9

;%9
ret void
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `-no-integrated-as` to your `llc` command ?

Comment: how old is your binutils?  are you up to date? (not with the distro but with gnu).

Comment: Yes, now I added -no-integrated-as command follow your recommend.   the command is llc -no-integrated-as -march=thumb -mattr=thumb2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 C:\backend\files\main.bc -o test.s   but still problem is not solved.

Comment: llc.exe is in llvm 10.0.0. make.exe was created on 2006.11.25 ...

Comment: Ok. Could you add the `-mccs` option tou your `arm-none-eabi-as` command ? And could you please answer `old_timer`'s question by executing the command `arm-none-eabi-as --version` ? thanks. By the way, your `llvm` is quite old... Is there any way you could get a more recent version ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. the result of "arm-none-eabi-as --version" command is as next "GNU assembler (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 9-2020-q2-update) 2.34.0.20200428
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-eabi'."

Comment: hm... Have to download llc 10.0.1?  and... could you teach me how use -mccs option on arm-none-eabi-as?

Comment: Using `-mccs` will not solve all of your  problems, just the first error: `a.s:4: Error: .def pseudo-op only available with -mccs flag.` - I am still getting the others, starting with `a.s:5: Error: unknown pseudo-op: '.scl'` I used the following command: `/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -mccs -c a.s -o a.o`

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded original code also.

Comment: Ok, but the original code is not the issue here.

Comment: I was forgotting the most important it... I'm sorry. I uploaded bitcode also. maybe... I think if problem may be on bitcode. The bitcode is compiled successfully by llc.exe.

Comment: I tried using the command as this.  "llc -mtriple=arm-none-eabi -march=thumb -mattr=thumb2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -float-abi=soft -thread-model=single -filetype=asm main.bc -o test.s"

Comment: And I executed command "make". The result is --> 
"arm-none-eabi-as c:/backend/files/test.s -o c:/backend/files/test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x08000000 c:/backend/files/test.o -o c:/backend/files/test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 08000000
arm-none-eabi-ld: c:/backend/files/test.o:(.ARM.exidx+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'"

Comment: This is good, you now have a linking error. You now need:
1) a minimal startup.s with a _start entry point that will set the stack, copy the .bss section into RAM, and call main().
2) find what the the library or object file containing `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0` you should link your application with. I would suggest to ask for support for this issue in an llvm-oriented forum.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will following your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem thanks for Frant's comment.

I updated bitcode file as below.

```
define void @main() #0
{
%1 = alloca i32, align 4
%2 = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 10, i32* %1, align 4
store i32 20, i32* %2, align 4
%3 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
%4 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
%5 = icmp ugt i32 %3, %4
br i1 %5, label %6, label %9

;%6
%7 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
%8 = add nsw i32 %7, 1
store i32 %8, i32* %1, align 4
br label %9

;%9
ret void
}

attributes #0 =
{
norecurse nounwind readnone
"stack-protector-buffer-size"="8"
}
```

And I updated llc command to as below.

```
llc -mtriple=arm-none-eabi -march=thumb -mattr=thumb2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 main.bc -o test.s
```

The result .s file is generated correctly.

Thanks for your interest in my problem.